# Office.context.roamingSettings.get(key) alternative function in VSTO c# project

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing a VSTO project where i want to save some user data using roaming settings
i searched for it and it is applicable only in javascript office.js
Is there any alternative that i can use in my VSTO project?

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save user settings in the user roaming profile. To add a user setting, go to project properties (right click the project => Properties), then navigate to the "Settings" tab and add your user setting there:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/settings-page-project-designer

Answer (score 0):

JS addin roaming settings are stored in the Exchange mailbox outside of the visible (IPM) folder tree. Outlook itself stores its global settings (e.g., categories etc.) in a hidden message (each folder has two contents tables - regular and hidden) in one of the default folders, such as Inbox or Calendar - you can see those messages in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMAPIFolder button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab.

You can access these message in your VSTO project through [MAPIFolder.GetStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.getstorage?view=outlook-pia).

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden items in Outlook. That is how roaming settings are stored by web add-ins. The Outlook object model provides the `StorageItem` object which is stored at the folder level, allowing it to roam with the account and be available online or offline.

The Outlook object model does not provide any collection object for `StorageItem` objects. However, you can use `Folder.GetTable` to obtain a `Table` with all the hidden items in a `Folder`, when you specify the `TableContents` parameter as `olHiddenItems`. Be aware, if keeping your data private is of a high concern, you should encrypt the data before storing it.

Once you have obtained a `StorageItem` object, you can do the following to store solution data:

- Add attachments to the item for storage.
- Use explicit built-in properties of the item such as `Body` to store custom data.
- Add custom properties to the item using `UserProperties.Add` method. Note that in this case, the optional `AddToFolderFields` and `DisplayFormat` arguments of the `UserProperties.Add` method will be ignored.
- Use the `PropertyAccessor` object to get or set custom properties.

For more information on storing solution data in Outlook see [Storing Data for Solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/solution-storage/storing-data-for-solutions).